# Awk: Sum up column values across multiple files with identical column layout

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I have a number of files with the same header:

COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4

You can ignore COL1-COL3. COL4 contains a number. Each file contains about 200 rows. I am trying to sum up across the rows. For example:

File 1

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
 x    y   z    3
 a    b   c    4
```

File 2

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
 x     y    z   5 
 a     b    c   10
```

Then a new file is returned:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
 x     y    z   8 
 a     b    c   14
```

Is there a simple way to do this *without* AWK? I will use AWK if need be, I just thought there might be a simple one-liner that I could just run right away. The AWK script I have in mind feels a bit long.

Thanks

Comment: Are the COL1-3 same in all the files? Do they appear in the same order in all the files?

Comment: awk would be a good and optimal choice. Of course, not with one short line, but ... with 2 lines, yes, I would write it with 2 lines

Comment: You're thinking backwards - in any given text manipulation situation where there might be a length or complicated solution, awk **IS** the simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more option.

**The command:**

```
paste f{1,2}.txt | sed '1d' | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4+$8}' | awk 'BEGIN{print "COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4"}1'
```

**The result:**

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
x y z 8
a b c 14
```

**What it does:**

Test files:

```
$ cat f1.txt
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
 x    y   z    3
 a    b   c    4

$ cat f2.txt
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
 x     y    z   5
 a     b    c   10
```

Command: `paste f{1,2}.txt` 
Joins 2 files and gives output:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
 x    y   z    3     x     y    z   5
 a    b   c    4     a     b    c   10
```

Command: `sed '1d'` 
Is meant to remove header temporarily

Command: `awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4+$8}'` 
Returns COL1-3 and sums $4 and $8 from paste result.

Command: `awk 'BEGIN{print "COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4"}1'` 
Adds header back

**EDIT:** 
Following @mklement0 comment, he is right about header handling as I forgot the `NR==1` part.

So, I'll proxy his updated version here also:

```
paste f{1,2}.txt | awk '{ print $1, $2, $3, (NR==1 ? $4 : $4 + $8) }'
```

Comment: The OP said `I have a number of files...`. This solution will only work if that number is exactly 2 so YMMV with the real world data.

Comment: @EdMorton it wasn't specified how the number of files will be passed. The solution is easily expandable to give right input to `paste` and `awk` with the given case :) So, it is not mileage away from real world data ;)

Comment: If you tried to expand it to accommodate more files you'd have a headache dealing with those hard-coded header strings and once you fixed that it'd simply become one of the other posted solutions. Plus you simply never need sed when you're using awk, nor do you need pipes of awk commands. This is simply not a good approach.

Comment: For reference, I have about 23 files. I thought I would just have one file be the "base file", and I take each file and I sum on top of the base file.

Comment: @TimelordViktorious that would be an extremely inefficient, fragile, and completely unnecessary approach. You have multiple answers here that can sum the values across all of your files at once.

Answer (score 2):

If all files have the same *header* - ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '!f && FNR==1{ f=1; print $0 }FNR>1{ s[FNR]+=$NF; $NF=""; r[FNR]=$0 }
      END{ for(i=2;i<=FNR;i++) print r[i],s[i] }' File[12]
```

The output (for 2 files):

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
x y z 8
a b c 14
```

---

This approach can be applied to multiple files (in that case you may specify *globbing* `File*` for *filename expansion*)

Answer (score 2):

**Combining `paste` with `awk`**, as in [Kristo Mägi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44598145/45375), is your best bet:

- `paste` merges the corresponding lines from the input files,
- which sends a single stream of input lines to `awk`, with each input line containing all fields to sum up.

**Assuming a fixed number of input files and columns**, Kristo's answer can be **simplified** to (making processing much more efficient):

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{ print $1, $2, $3, (NR==1 ? $4 : $4 + $8) }'
```

<sup>Note: The above produces *space*-separated output columns, because `awk`'s default value for `OFS`, the output-field separator, is a single space.</sup>

---

Assuming that all files have the same column structure and line count, below is a **generalization of the solution**, which:

- generalizes to *more than 2 input files* (and more than 2 data rows)
- generalizes to *any number of fields*, as long as the field to sum up is the *last* one.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=( file1 file2 ) # array of input files
paste "${files[@]}" | awk -v numFiles=${#files[@]} -v OFS='\t' '
  {
    row = sep = ""
    for(i=1; i < NF/numFiles; ++i) { row = row sep $i; sep = OFS }
    sum = $(NF/numFiles) # last header col. / (1st) data col. to sum
    if (NR > 1) { for(i=2; i<=numFiles; ++i) sum += $(NF/numFiles * i) } # add other cols.
    printf "%s%s%s\n", row, OFS, sum
  }
'
```

Note that `\t` (the tab char.) is used to separate output fields and that, due to relying on `awk`'s default line-splitting into fields, preserving the exact input whitespace between fields is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

You state you have "a number of files". i.e., more than 2.

Given these 3 files (and should work with any number):

```
$ cat f1 f2 f3
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
 x    y   z    3
 a    b   c    4
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
 x     y    z   5 
 a     b    c   10 
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
 x     y    z   10 
 a     b    c   15
```

You can do:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{next}
     {sum[$1]+=$4}
     END{print "COL1 COL4"; 
         for (e in sum) print e, sum[e]} ' f1 f2 f3
COL1 COL4
x 18
a 29
```

It is unclear what you intend to do with COL2 or COL3, so I did not add that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
     NR==1 { print }
     { sum[FNR]+=$NF; sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*$/,""); pfx[FNR]=$0 }
     END { for(i=2;i<=FNR;i++) print pfx[i] sum[i] }
' file1 file2
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
 x     y    z   8
 a     b    c   14
```

The above will work robustly and efficiently with any awk on any UNIX system, with any number of input files and with any contents of those files. The only potential problem would be that it has to retain the equivalent of 1 of those files in memory so if each file was absolutely massive then you may exhaust available memory.

Comment: To avoid recreating `pfx` for _every_ input file, it's probably worth guarding it with a `NR == FNR` conditional.

Comment: @mklement0 yup should be $NF, corrected now thanks. Yeah, I could add the NR==FNR condition but I honestly doubt it'll make a noticable difference so I'm not going to bother.

Comment: @EdMorton what happens if one wants to sum entries across multiple columns, not just entries of a particular column.

Comment: @Boogeyman depends on the requirements, please ask a new question.